# ASP.NET MVC - Deploying with IIS 7.5 and framework .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I try to deploy an ASP.NET MVC4 website and I got some issue. When I'm launching the website through IIS, I got an error which highlights a line in my web.config : the  **targetframework 4.5**

I've read on the internet that I could change it by 4.0 to make it work. I did it but now I got another error which says that it is **impossible to load the System.Net.Http assembly or its dependecies**.

I'm pretty lost and really new to this stuff. Any idea about it?

EDIT : Here's the error message.

> The 'targetFramework' attribute in the  element of the
>   Web.config file is used only to target version 4.0 and later of the
>   .NET Framework (for example, '').
>   The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is
>   later than the installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a
>   valid target version of the .NET Framework, or install the required
>   version of the .NET Framework.

Comment: please share the exact error message rather than describing the error

Comment: Looks like your server needs .NET 4.5 installed?

Comment: not recommended but deleting the web.config file usually works, unless you have important stuff in it, (TEMP FIX ONLY)

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "change it by 4.0", do you mean change the App Pool to 4.0?  Or do you mean you changed the line in your web.config to say 4.0 instead of 4.5?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but what if you directly put existed version of dll which exists on your server in your web.config. 
like this

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
</runtime>
```